# Copy range upon condition to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var MASTERSHEET_IDFLEXREG = '1XHtCB2iq4vggAmWQ85GOoazzOVhLRWJs_Akp_eTAdrc';
var MASTERSHEET_IDUZK = '1ZXY4Q2SZT-4E8hu1R5Wfb_h4r7HQ2TZbshOxMqrYg6M';


function FlexRegtoLijstUZK() {
  // Neemt copy van lijst UZKen 
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERSHEET_IDFLEXREG);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Lijst UZKen'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:Q').activate();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERSHEET_IDUZK);
  

  var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Lijst UZKen");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("IMPORT_Flexview regulier");
    
  // The below makes the highlighted cells the range that will be copied.

  var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = source_range.getValues();
  
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
}
```

```
function CopyLijstUZKenREG()
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERSHEET_IDFLEXREG).getSheetByName('Lijst UZKen');
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++)
  {  
     var rowData = data[i];
     if (rowData[16] != "" && rowData[17]=="") 
     {
       sourceSheet. getRange(i+1,18). setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy"));FlexRegtoLijstUZK();
     }         
  }
}
```

I would like to copy-paste a row of 1 spreadsheet upon a condition (rowData[17] should be empty) to another spreadsheet.
With above script it copies the whole sheet and not the specified row.